# Deleting a folder with files in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, directory

What is the proper syntax when deleting a folder with files in laravel 5.2?

Here is my syntax when deleting the folder from the DB and DIR

```
$folder = Folder::find($id);
$folder_path = storage_path('locker').'/'. $folder->folder_title;
$folder->delete();
 `rmdir($folder_path);`
\Session::flash('success', 'Folder Deleted!');
return back();
```

Answer (score 33):

After much frustration I got the solution.

Use '**File**' instead of '**Storage**'

```
File::deleteDirectory($path);
```

Comment: this solution is not working for me

Answer (score 19):

> The deleteDirectory may be used to remove a directory and all of its files

```
Storage::deleteDirectory($directory);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#directories

Comment: It only deletes from my view but and the folder itself is still on my storage directory and database record of files. The only thing that was removed is the database record which is the folder title.

Answer (score 1):

Delete a Folder with Storage or File Class

> **Storage::deleteDirectory($path);**

[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-a-folder-with-storage-or-file-class)