# How can I delete folder in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

If I delete file like this :

```
$destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $id;
$result = File::delete($destinationPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

It works

But if I delete folder like this :

```
$destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $id;
File::delete($destinationPath);
```

It does not work

Why delete folder does not work?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you should check google first, got solution in first link :) `delete directory laravel` this was my search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a folder with files in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207731/deleting-a-folder-with-files-in-laravel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use the wrong method. You need to use `deleteDirectory` and not `delete`:

```
$destinationPath = public_path('img/products/'. $id);
File::deleteDirectory($destinationPath);
```

Comment: Which one class need to be included for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete folder with files than use:-

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::deleteDirectory($public_path);
```